# How would one describe "wood" with a gradient, yet somewhat striped color?

Tags: diction

I am currently attempting to describe a painting of wood for an assignment, but I quickly ran into an issue, as I'm required to use different diction. To be more quick to the point, how would I describe wood that is somewhat striped, but at the same time somewhat blended in color? I can't call it **oak** in color because of the obvious color changes throughout, but at the same time I *cannot* call it **striped** because of the blend and somewhat smooth transition in colors.

How would one describe this?

Note: This isn't a famous piece of art, in case any of you are wondering (or might wonder or will wonder?), its just a painting at a local art exhibition. Additionally, I was unfortunately not able to get any kind of picture due to certain circumstances, so this description is the best that can be done.

Comment: In any sensible system 'oak' would include all the variations that exist in the timber of the Quercus species. Can you clarify: are you talking about bark, about wood grain? Is it cut with or across the grain? Sawn or split? Is it weathered/stained timber, is it sun or salt bleached, wet or dry, rotting, painted, varnished , polished, sanded... Is it depicted in close up or distant view? If we know the cause of the colour change it will help us to assist you.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are describing natural wood grain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider **streaky**, which does not imply the high contrast of a "striped" pattern.

From [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/streaky):

> adj.
>
> Something that is streaky is marked with long stripes that are a different colour to the rest of it.